# Codeigniter 3 - Set Flashdata Array issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I need help about CodeIgniter **`$this->session->set_flashdata`** array.

I think my code is so long, is there any way to simplify my code?

Script at my **views**

```
<?php 
for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
   if($this->session->flashdata("'warning".$i."'")) 
      echo $this->session->flashdata("'warning".$i."'");
   if($this->session->flashdata("'info".$i."'"))
      echo $this->session->flashdata("'info".$i."'");
}
?>
<form action="xxxx/insertMember" method="post">
   <?php for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) { ?>
      <label>Username <?php echo $i; ?></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username[<?php echo $i; ?>]>
   <?php } ?>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Script at my **controller**

```
...
parent::__construct();
$max = 5;

public function insertMember() {
....form was validated & return true...
   $name = $this->input->post('username',TRUE);
   $a = 1;
   $b = 1;
   for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
      if($name[$i] != '') {
         //check username was registered on database or not.
         $doCheck[$i] = $this->model->check($name[$i]);

         //if already registered
         if(!empty($doCheck[$i])) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("'warning".$a."'",$name[$i].' was registered');
            $a++;
         }

         //if not registered
         else {
            $this->model->insert($name[$i]);
            $this->session->set_flashdata("'warning".$b."'",$name[$i].' sucessfully registered');
            $b++;
         }

         redirect('registerpage');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it is different answer related to that question but its efficient and simple. You can set the array like this:

```
$userDetails = array();  // declare the array

for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    if($name[$i] != '') {
       //check username was registered on database or not.
       $doCheck[$i] = $this->model->check($name[$i]);
       //if already registered

       if(!empty($doCheck[$i])) {
            $userDetails["user_name$i"] = array('userid'=> $name[$i], 'is_reg'=>1); //set array that user is already register
            $this->session->set_flashdata('UserData', $userDetails);
       }
       //if not registered
       else {
          $this->model->insert($name[$i]);
          $userDetails["user_name$i"] = array('userid'=> $name[$i], 'is_reg'=>0); //set array that user is not already register
         $this->session->set_flashdata('UserData', $userDetails);
       }
   redirect('registerpage');
}
```

Get array

```
$userdata = $this->session->flashdata('UserData');
print_r($userdata);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers.
How about this code ?
$userDetails['user_name1']
$userDetails['user_name2']
$userDetails['user_name3']

and how to retrieve it ? thank you dude.

Comment: I have changed the answer. Please check now and let me know.

Comment: I will check it now.. Thank you for your help Anand !

Comment: That's working well Anand !  I have another question about php & javascript, can you help me ?

Comment: Yes please but ask as a separate question

Answer (score 1):

This seems more like a code review question (like Alive to Die comments), so I'm not entirely sure what you are needing.  For the most part, your code looks fine.  I have a few things to consider, but they are mainly preferential.

You could adjust the **View** output within the form.

```
<?php 
    for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) { 
        echo '<label>Username ' . $i . ' </label><input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username[' . $i . ']>';
    }
?>
```

In your **Controller**, you could also initiate `$a` and `$b` differently, as mentioned in this Stack Overflow article: [Assign same value to multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651594/assign-same-value-to-multiple-variables).

```
$a = $b = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for remembering me about `$a = $b = 1;`, I was forgot it.